# Proof that all maximal independent sets of a matroid have the same cardinality

Tags: solution-verification, matroids

I'm trying to prove the following statement about some matroid $(X,\mathcal{I})$:

For every subset $Y\subseteq X$, all maximal independent sets contained in $\mathcal{I}$ have equal size.

*Proof:*
Assume for contradiction that there exist two maximal independent sets $X_1, X_2$
such that $\left|X_1\right|< \left|X_2\right|$. Then, $\exists x\in X_2-X_1$ where
$X_1\cup\left\{x\right\}\in I$. Then, $X_1\subseteq X_1\cup\left\{x\right\}$. Since $X_1\cup\left\{x\right\}$ is independent, $X_1$ cannot be a maximal independent set, which contradicts our assumption.
The same contradiction follows if $\left|X_2\right|<\left|X_1\right|$. Thus, by the well-ordering of cardinality, $\left|X_2\right|=\left|X_1\right|$

Is this proof valid? If not, where is my mistake? In the future, how could I be more careful to avoid such mistakes?

Comment: The whole argument hinges on whether this is true: "Then, $\exists x\in X_2-X_1$ where $X_1\cup\left\{x\right\}\in I$".  I haven't dealt with more general matroids, but with "finite dimensional" matroids you'd use an exchange condition to prove this.

Comment: The proof is correct, but the statement shouldn't have the part "For every subset $Y\subseteq X$". Furthermore, the statement holds not just for *some* matroid, it holds for *all* matroids.

Comment: "Then, ∃x∈X2−X1 where X1∪{x}∈I". This is an axiom of matroids (for the definition I'm using), although there are many equivalent formulations that use different axioms